# What does the --color=auto option for GNU grep mean?

Tags: grep

AFAICT, neither the man page for GNU `grep`, nor `info grep`, deigns to spell out what `--color=auto` means.

I must be one of the very few people on the planet for which the meaning of this option is not immediately obvious.

I surmise that `--color=auto` "is *SOMEWHERE* in-between" `--color=never` and `--color=always`, but that still leaves too much unspecified.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The rules are the same as for `ls`, which does a better job documenting it in `man ls`.  Quoting:

> Using  color  to distinguish file types is disabled both by default and
>      with --color=never.  With --color=auto, ls emits color codes only  when
>      standard  output is connected to a terminal.  The LS_COLORS environment
>      variable can change the settings.  Use the dircolors command to set it.

So it will make the command only add the color formatting when the output is going to a terminal and not, say, when it is going to a pipe where the program consuming the pipe might not handle the color formatting well.

Comment: Yup, the main times I've run into this were piping into less. If you use `less -R` you can get match highlighting but you need to specify `--color=always` to grep for it to work.

Answer (score 10):

Since `grep` is a GNU program another option might be having a look at the source code.

---

Internally grep tests the `static int color_option` for either `0`,`1` or `2`.

- `0` never use colorized output
- `1` always use colors
- `2` only use colors when printing to a terminal

Now when you hand over `--color=auto` to grep as an argument on your CLI, it internally sets the variable `color_option` to `2`.

If `color_option` equals `2` `grep` then further tests whether `STDOUT` is linked to a terminal or the user disabled colorized outpit via `shell environment variables`.
If the former one is true and colorized output is permitted, `grep` then continues with evaluating which colors should be used and in the end finally prints out to your `CLI` in color.

---

source: (grep 2.21)

```
grep.c line 306, 2374, 2440
colorize-posix.c line 36
man isatty
```