# Colored grep output: Not GREP_OPTIONS not alias

Tags: grep, colors

I want colored output of `grep`.

.... But

- Strategy 1: GREP_OPTIONS. But this is deprecated. See http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html
- Stragegy 2: GREP_COLORS look like a solution at the first sight, but this does something different.
- Strategy 3: alias. This does not work for `find ... | xargs grep`, since xargs does not evaluate aliases.
- Strategy 4: Write a simple wrapper script. No, I think this is too dirty and makes more trouble than it solves.
- Strategy 5: patch the source code
- Strategy 6: Contact grep developers, ask for a replacement of GREP_OPTIONS
- Strategy NICE-and-EASY: ... this is missing. I have no clue.

How to solve this?

Comment: You have rejected two suggestions to use a wrapper script (your Strategy 4) as "not really an answer".  Can you describe what is "dirty", "troublesome", or "not really an answer" about it?  Maybe that's a separate problem that can be worked around.

Comment: strategy 5 is patch the source code and set [`color_option` to `2`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236977)...

Comment: @JigglyNaga here is my explanation why a wrapper script is not a solution. Our team manages several servers. Less then thousand at the moment, but the count is increasing. Yes, we use configuration management and it would be easy to deploy a script to all of them. But I want things to be easy and straightforward (think of new members in the team. I don't want to confuse them). The `--color` option already has the value `auto`. I just don't know why you can't activate it by default.

Comment: You should use strategy 4 or 5 -- I'd prefer strategy 4 with a minimal dash/sh script (`exec grep --color=auto "$@"`), optionally with a different name (`grepc` or `colorgrep`). This has neglible overhead (and no extra concurrent processes at runtime). The reason you have labeled them *"not easy enough"* is the fact that you do not see this feature useful enough to spend the (relatively little) one-time effort to implement it, and are seeking for someone else to do it for you. Because of this, your *"not really an answer"* comments to the posted answers are quite rude.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Yes, you are right "not really an answer" sounds rude. I am not a native speaker. Which wording (transferring the same message) would be better?

Answer (score 16):

Some of the reasons OP has stated are not grounded in fact (i.e. a lack of understanding of how shell scripting works and lack of understanding how a simple wrapper script does not impact performance).

#### In this answer I demonstrate that strategy 4 has is actually a good solution for a number of reasons (easy to implement, low overhead, flexible for all any use-case, etc etc):

On most distributions, `grep` is installed in `/bin` (typical) or `/usr/bin` (OpenSUSE, maybe others), and default `PATH` contains `/usr/local/bin` before `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. This means that if you create `/usr/local/bin/grep` with

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /bin/grep --color=auto "$@"
```

where `/bin/sh` is a POSIX-compatible shell provided by your distribution, usually bash or dash. If `grep` is in `/usr/bin`, then make that

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/grep --color=auto "$@"
```

#### performance overhead of a wrapper script is minimal

The overhead of this script is minimal. The `exec` statement means that the script interpreter is replaced by the `grep` binary; this means that the shell does not remain in memory while `grep` is being executed. Thus, the only overhead is one extra execution of the script interpreter, i.e. a small latency in wall clock time. The latency is roughly constant (varies only depending on whether `grep` and `sh` are already in page cache or not, and on how much I/O bandwidth is available), and does not depend on how long `grep` executes or how much data it processes.

So, how long is that latency, i.e. the overhead added by the wrapper script?

To find out, create the above script, and run

```
time /bin/grep --version
time /usr/local/bin/grep --version
```

On my machine, the former takes 0.005s real time (across a large number of runs), whereas the latter takes 0.006s real time. Thus, the overhead of using the wrapper on my machine is 0.001s (or less) per invocation.

This is insignificant.

I also fail to see anything "dirty" about this, because many common applications and utilities use the same approach. To see the list of such on your machine in `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, just run

```
file /bin/* /usr/bin/* | sed -ne 's/:.*shell script.*$//p'
```

On my machine, the above output includes `egrep`, `fgrep`, `zgrep`, `which`, `7z`, `chromium-browser`, `ldd`, and `xfig`, which I use quite often. Unless you consider your entire distribution "dirty" for relying on wrapper scripts, you have no reason to consider such wrapper scripts "dirty".

#### possible problems by putting a wrapper script on your PATH

If only human users (as opposed to scripts) are using the version of grep that defaults to color support if output is to a terminal, then the wrapper script can be named `colorgrep` or `cgrep` or whatever the OP sees fit.

This avoids all possible compatibility issues, because the behaviour of `grep` does not change at all.

---

Enabling `grep` options with a wrapper script, but in a way that avoids any new problems:

We can easily rewrite the wrapper script to support a custom `GREP_OPTS` even if `GREP_OPTIONS` were not supported (as it is already deprecated). This way users can simply add `export "GREP_OPTIONS=--color=auto"` or similar to their profile. `/usr/local/bin/grep` is then

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /bin/grep $GREP_OPTIONS "$@"
```

Note that there are no quotes around `$GREP_OPTIONS`, so that users can specify more than one option.

On my system, executing `time /usr/local/bin/grep --version` with `GREP_OPTIONS` empty, or with `GREP_OPTIONS=--color=auto`, is just as fast as the previous version of the wrapper script; i.e., typically takes one millisecond longer to execute than plain `grep`.

#### This last version is the one I'd personally recommend for use.

In summary, OP's strategy 4:

- is aready recommended by `grep` developers
- is trivial to implement (two lines)
- has insignificant overhead (one millisecond extra latency per invocation on this particular laptop; easily verified on each machine)
- can be implemented as a wrapper script that adds `GREP_OPTS` support (to replace deprecated/unsupported `GREP_OPTIONS`)
- can be implemented (as `colorgrep`/`cgrep`) that does not affect scripts or existing users at all

Because it is a technique that is widely used in Linux distributions already, it is a common technique and not "dirty".

If implemented as a separate wrapper (`colorgrep`/`cgrep`), it cannot create new problems since it does not affect `grep` behaviour at all. If implemented as a wrapper script that adds `GREP_OPTS` support, using `GREP_OPTS=--color=auto` has exactly the same risks (wrt. problems with existing scripts) that upstream adding default `--color=auto` would. Thus, the comment that this "creates more problems than it solves" is completely incorrect: no additional problems are created.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation you provide with first strategy says:

> Please use an alias or script instead. For example, if grep is in the directory ‘/usr/bin’ you can prepend $HOME/bin to your PATH and create an executable script $HOME/bin/grep containing the following:

```
#! /bin/sh
export PATH=/usr/bin
exec grep --color=auto --devices=skip "$@"
```

So if the alias is impossible for you, the wrapper script is the only way.

Answer (score 4):

The reason the `GREP_OPTIONS` variable is deprecated is that it tends to cause problems when `grep` is called somewhere in a script and the script doesn't work with the alternative options that come from the variable. If you write a wrapper script for `grep` then you have the same problem, *unless you give it a different name*.

```
$ cat ~/bin/cgrep
#!/bin/sh
exec grep --color=always "$@"
$ find … -exec cgrep … {} +
```

Alternatively, store your favorite options in a variable. In shells other than zsh, this is cumbersome if the options contain wildcard characters (`\[*?`), but otherwise you can just use the variable unquoted to get a command with arguments.

```
cgrep=(grep --color=always)
find … -exec $cgrep … {} +
```

Note that GNU and BSD grep can process a directory tree recursively, which alleviates the need for `find` in combination with `grep` most of the time.

Comment: That is Strategy 4... not really an answer.

Comment: @guettli, that's the correct answer. If you want a command with a different behaviour that `grep`'s, you need a command with a different name, or else if you keep the same name, you'll break scripts that expect the original/standard behaviour. That is the cleanest and doesn't _cause additional trouble_.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes you are right. This is the correct answer according to your point of view.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question, but to address Strategy 3:

> Strategy 3: alias. This does not work for find ... | xargs grep, since xargs does not evaluate aliases.

From `help alias`:

```
alias: alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]
    A trailing space in VALUE causes the next word to be checked for
    alias substitution when the alias is expanded.
```

Therefore, make an alias for `xargs` with a trailing space:

```
alias xargs='xargs '
alias chgrep='\grep --color=auto --include=\*.{c,cc,cpp,h,hh,hpp} -r'

find /path/ -type f | xargs chgrep 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to use an alias (strategy 3). If you really do care about the `xargs` command, you can still override it with a bash function.

```
alias grep='grep --color'
xargs() {
    local args
    for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++))
    do
            if [[ "-E -L -P -I -s -d" == *"${!i}"* ]]; then
                    ((i=i+1))
            elif [[ ${!i:0:1} != "-" ]]; then
                    if [[ ${!i} == "grep" ]]; then
                            args="--color"
                    fi
                    /usr/bin/xargs ${@:1:i} $args ${@:i+1}
                    return;
            fi
    done
}
```

But this is not better than using a wrapper command which seems to be the recommended solution by the `grep` team:

```
/usr/local/bin/grep:

#!/bin/bash
/bin/grep --color "$@"
```

**In my humble opinion, you should contact the `grep` developer team to ask them to provide a simple replacement to the `GREP_OPTIONS` variable which will enable the color in `grep` according to some environment variable.**

It would be quite simple for them to enable by default the `color` option or when the `GREP_COLORS` has been set.

Comment: Thank you for "... you should contact the grep developer team...". This gives me positive feedback. Now I know that I am not the only one who thinks something is missing here.

Comment: I added your comment "... you should contact the grep developer team..." as strategy6 to the question. Up to now this is my favourite answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution from the top answer by @NominalAnimal but with the usual `grep: ...` in warnings (instead of `/bin/grep: ...`):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
exec -a grep /bin/grep --color=auto "$@"
```

Comment: I know how to write wrappers. A wrapper is not a solution in this context.

Comment: @guettli Well, the answer wasn't meant to address precisely your situation... If comments had the same formatting features as answers, that would be a comment. (And I had similar edits rejected as not intended by the original author or something.) As for your situation, I think a proper literal answer to your question is: that another "Strategy NICE-and-EASY" doesn't exist.